# npm install git repository without package.json

Tags: git, npm

I have a project that depends on several third-party libs.

My package.json looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "vendor-name": "git://github.com/vendor/name.git#v1.1",
    ...
}
```

This works as long as the `vendor-name` repository contains a `package.json`.

If there's not such a file, I get:

```
npm ERR! path /var/folders/0l/temp-folder/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
```

Actually, a `npm install git://github.com/vendor/name.git#v1.1` does not work, too.

So my question is:
Is there a way to install (include) git repositories (in the `dependencies`) that do not have a `package.json`?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  If the repo is not yours, fork it, and add your own `package.json` file to it.  Perhaps, even submit a pull request.

Comment: I thought about using Napa as suggested, but your solution is better in my opinion.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes you can with this package: https://npmjs.org/package/napa

Comment: This answer has not aged well :p
I think I prefer using **bower installer** for this kind of scenarios

Answer (score 19):

What napa do seems to be overengineered. I think just adding install script into the package.json is enough for you.

```
"scripts": {
    "install": "git clone https://github.com/vendor/name.git -b v1.1 node_modules/name"
}
```

Comment: This might cause issue when re-running it again, as the clone will probably fail.

Comment: @Danosaure You could use this as the install command instead:
`if cd node_modules/name; then git pull; else git clone https://github.com/vendor/name.git node_modules/name; fi`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still hoping to do this without `napa` as a dependency, I use this...

```json
  "scripts": {
    "install": "rimraf external_modules/<org>/<repo> && git clone https://github.com/<org>/<repo>.git external_modules/<org>/<repo>"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
  },
```

Answer (score -2):

no that is not possible according to the [npm documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html)

Comment: The link is dead