# Using a task runner without package.json

Tags: gruntjs, build-automation

I'm evaluating task runners, Grunt and Gulp in particular, but there's one thing I dislike about both of them: the fact that they require a `package.json` file for your project. This is even though your project might not even be an npm project in the first place. In my case, I'm already using `composer.json`, which basically does the exact same thing.

I ended up creating my `package.json` like this:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-phpcs": "~0.2.3",
    "grunt-phplint": "0.0.5",
    "grunt-phpdocumentor": "~0.4.1"
  }
}
```

Note that I'm not maintaining the version number, as that is unnecessary overhead. This works though, in the sense that I can run my grunt tasks after executing `npm install`. I feel that I should be able to do without this file though. I read that it's possible to use Grunt without a `package.json`, but my take is that you'd then have to install the node modules manually, which is more overhead. Gulp is no different, or at least I found no evidence to the contrary.

So the question is, are there any task runners that don't require you to define your project's metadata twice, need only a single file, and are not *too* bleeding edge?

Comment: Grunt is a node module, and it has dependencies which are managed by `npm`, thus yes, you must have a `package.json` file. Grunt (or Gulp for that matter) would have no way of importing its dependencies without a package management file of some sort, and they have chosen to use `npm` for this. If you're asking for recommendations on a different task runner, well, that's really not what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: @jakerella It is not true that having a `package.json` file is a must. Yes, it could use `npm` as the backend for installing dependencies, but that does not necessarily require a `package.json` file. The grunt CLI tool could have some logic that takes requirements from the Gruntfile, adds a `0.0.0` version and runs `npm install`. In fact, there are already packages that do something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143173/npm-install-git-repository-without-package-json

Comment: While technically true, that could quickly become cumbersome as you would have to maintain all packages yourself, including knowing when there are updates. The fact is, that's how Grunt expects and recommends that you to use the tool.

Comment: @jakerella Not at all. You don't seem to understand my suggestion. I just found out that BLDR does exactly what I'm describing, only it's PHP based and uses composer as package management backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself, the only thing I could find that seems to fit my requirements is [bldr](http://bldr.io/). It is PHP based, uses composer as package management backend, and does it without hijacking the `composer.json` you might already be using, as it uses `bldr.json` instead. It also does not require you to add metadata to the file that describes your bldr dependencies. Here's an example dependencies file (taken from http://docs.bldr.io/en/latest/blocks.html):

```
{
    "require": {
        "acme/demo-block": "@stable"
    }
}
```

Then, when you run `bldr install`, your dependencies are installed and you can run your bldr tasks.