# Why grunt as devDependencies inside package.json

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, package.json

I'm new with grunt, I started learning it ten minutes ago and I was wondering why grunt must be listed in the package.json as dependencies. 
This means that when someone will install my module for node, for example, npm will install to him also grunt. But I actually need grunt just to minify stuff and push them to my git repo and it isn't needed to run actually the node script.

Did I miss something?

UPDATE: Now that I know how to handle grunt I can say that I don't like it so much. I find grunt too tied with npm. This post explain perfectly my feelings about this task runner: [Using a task runner without package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703049/using-a-task-runner-without-package-json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**dev**Dependencies are only installed when doing `npm install` in the *root* of the package. When someone installs your package, only the `dependencies` are installed.

So grunt in `devDependencies` is exactly what you want, you need grunt when **dev**eloping your package.