# How to include old es5 Javascript from CDN in Electron app

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, electron, ecmascript-5

I am wanting to build an Electron client which utilises the following libraries which are hosted on a CDN and written in ES5.

```
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/toots/shine/master/js/dist/libshine.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/webcast/libsamplerate.js/master/dist/libsamplerate.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/webcast/taglib.js/master/dist/taglib.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/webcast/webcast.js/master/lib/webcast.js"></script>
```

How can I include these libraries in my Electron app?

Is there a way to bundle these libraries into an importable library?

Comment: Install them with NPM?

Comment: Unfortunately they are not NPM modules

Comment: First of all, the first thing I've checked is NPM package, taglib.js. And there are workarounds for non-NPM packages, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143173/npm-install-git-repository-without-package-json

Comment: The above scripts would need to be compressed as tar balls and the code would need to be exportable. as in `module.exports = /* library code */`. If you look at the code, it is raw, ES5 code so there are no imports or exports. I am trying to find a solution which would allow me to include this code within Electron. If this was a web app, I would simply include the script tags but as far as I am aware, this is not possible within Electron so I need to package them up somehow without refactoring the code as there is a lot there and I would likely break it.

Comment: Why? You just install them via NPM and use with <script>. Even with no <script>, non-modular JS can be evaluated when being imported with `require` like global scripts (this may fail if the app is in strict mode and the script uses `this` to refer to a global).